# (jython/ python)Can't seem to get the image copy I made in jython outside of my def

Tags: python, image, copy, return, jython

Hi I have a single block of code for an excersize I'm trying to write that I can't figure out why the copied image is not callable outside of the definition.  Also I don't understand why or what to put in the brackets of the definition, or why I would, as the excersize is asking me to have the definition title written exactly as I currently have it.  Also, why would I use the statement "return" as shown in some other code examples I've seen?

Do you spot any redundancies too? =\

Here's the Code:

```
def makeCopyOfAPicture(picOriginal):
    source = pickAFile()
    picOriginal = makePicture(source)
    picWidth = getWidth(picOriginal)
    picHeight = getHeight(picOriginal)
    picCopy = makeEmptyPicture(picWidth, picHeight)
    targetX = 0
    for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(picOriginal)):
        targetY = 0
        for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(picOriginal)):
            color = getColor(getPixel(picOriginal,sourceX,sourceY))
            setColor(getPixel(picCopy, targetX, targetY), color)
            targetY = targetY + 1
        targetX = targetX + 1
    show(picOriginal)
    show(picCopy)
#   print(picCopy)
#   print(picOriginal)
    return picCopy

makeCopyOfAPicture(picOriginal)
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mypic = makeCopyOfAPicture(picOriginal)
```

Then use `mypic` outside the function . You have to assign what a function returns to a variable if you want to use it outside the function.

Comment: No worries, it is exactly what `picOriginal = makePicture(source)` etc.. is doing in the function

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now, thanks!

I've also found out what return does! hooray!

Comment: See at the top of the definition, `def makeCopyOfAPicture(picOriginal):` I am not sure what picOriginal is doing unless it looks inside of the definition, or if I'm just creating a variable called picOriginal when i write that definition ling?  i `print picOriginal` and nothing exists just below the `def makeCopyOfAPicture(picOriginal):`

Comment: `picOriginal = makePicture(source)` creates a new variable `picOriginal` so that means from there on that is used when referenced so what you pass in never gets used. It looks like you are just meant to pick a file using the `pickAFile()`  not actually pass anything to the function